# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `onClick` of type `object` supplied to `ButtonBase`, expected `function`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mobx, mobx-react

```
<Fab raised="true" size="small" color="primary" variant="extended"
        onClick={props.Store.fetchFromServer}
```

and

```
this.fetchFromServer = async () => {
await console.log('test')
}
```

works fine.

But when changed to following

```
<Fab raised="true" size="small" color="primary" variant="extended"
        onClick={props.Store.fetchFromServer('test')}
```

and

```
this.fetchFromServer = async (val) => {
await console.log(val)
}
```

throw following error, what I am missing?

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `onClick` of type `object` supplied to `ButtonBase`, expected `function`
```

this did not help much 
[Failed prop type: Invalid prop `onClick` of type `object` supplied to `Button`, expected `function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006608/failed-prop-type-invalid-prop-onclick-of-type-object-supplied-to-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing because once you pass a parameter to the function, you are calling it, and therefore it is now returning a value (and thus becomes an `object`). The way to get around this is by passing an anonymous function into the `onClick()` event like so, basically making it into a function:

```
onClick={e => props.Store.fetchFromServer('test')}
```

Here is a test example to show you the types of functions being called in different ways:

```js
a = function (val) {}
b = async (val) => {
  /* await console.log(val) */
}

console.log(typeof(a))
console.log(typeof(b))
console.log(typeof(a('test1')))
console.log(typeof(b('test2')))
console.log(typeof(() => b('test3')))
```

Comment: Thanks Hybrid, I am getting this which I can suppress by using no-unused-vars. But wondering if there is better way to around it....
 [ts] 'e' is declared but its value is never read. [6133]
[eslint] 'e' is defined but never used. [no-unused-vars]

Comment: You can suppress this message by removing `e` from the parameter signature if it is not going to be passed to your function, i.e. `onClick={() => props.Store.fetchFromServer('test')}`