# Bug problem : Failed prop type: The prop `onClick` is marked as required in `Letter`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, so for educational purposes I'm building a hangman game. But I incurr in a problem, from the snippet below the `onclick` event is unrecognized as a function. I am supposing the problem could stem by a not proper use of `this`, but is only an assumption.

definition

```
const Letter = ({ index, letter, onClick }) => (
  <div className={`letter`} onClick={() => onClick(index)}>
    <button >
      {letter}
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

render part

```
ALPHABET.map((letter, index) => (
    <Letter
      letter={letter}
      index={index}
      key={index}
      onClick={this.addLetter(letter,usedLetters)}
    />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed prop type: Invalid prop \`onClick\` of type \`object\` supplied to \`ButtonBase\`, expected \`function\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526271/failed-prop-type-invalid-prop-onclick-of-type-object-supplied-to-buttonbas)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
onClick={this.addLetter(letter,usedLetters}
```

You are invoking the function as soon as the component renders.

Assuming you are defining a class-component and addLetter is an arrow function inside it like so:

```
addLetter = (letter, usedLetters) => {
  ...
}
```

You can rework the onClick property to this and it will still require the arguments your defined by default.

```
onClick={this.addLetter}
```

Also, you never passed in `usedLetters` as a property to `Letter`

```
<Letter
  letter={letter}
  usedLetters={usedLetters}
  index={index}
  key={index}
  onClick={this.addLetter(letter,usedLetters)}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. I understand the syntax better now